# Каким образом лучше построить таблицу в WindowsForms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[image: Шапка таблицы]

У меня имеется таблица с такой вот шапкой, где куча объединенных ячеек, в некоторых местах текст развернуть на 90 градусов и т.д. Мне нужно иметь такую таблицу в windows Form-е для дальнейшего программного ее заполнения.
Пока я нашел единственный вариант, это импортировать файл excel  в dataGridview и уже работать там.
Есть ли еще варианты создания такой таблицы непосредственно в формах?
В программировании новичок, строго прошу вопрос не критиковать.
Весь функционал программы пишу на C#.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я думаю это невозможно сделать на винформах, на Wpf определенно можно

Comment: Дизайн в WinForms, ИМХО, боль, но вполне реализуемая "боль". Вот допустим [вариант](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4a3f5639-8c2b-4a86-ae08-28abb9c8f845/how-to-merge-two-column-headers-in-a-datagridview?forum=vbgeneral#:~:text=You%20need%20to%20customer%20your%20datagridvew), правда на VB, но переделать под C# труда не составит. Или [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30118206/6808809) пример объединения ячеек, на его основе думаю тоже можно сделать то, что вам надо.